# Android send SMS through an app and keep it on phone

Tags: android, sms

I am doing an app to send SMS from my computer through my android phone using a bluetooth connection.
I use my android phone to send the SMS with the following code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, MessageText, null, null);
```

I don't care about the notification yet.
However, when I send a SMS using the app, I would like to be able to see it when I come back in the basic messaging service of my phone. But it isn't the case here.

Have you got some ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending and SMS through SMSManager will never add the text to the other texting app, you have 2 options

1) The "correct" android way using intents (this will take users out of the app)

```
Intent sendSMS = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendSMS.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sendSMS.putExtra("address", "5558675309");
sendSMS.putExtra("sms_body","Your message here");
startActivity(sendSMS);
```

2) The undocumented way that seems to work most of the time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706526/show-outbound-texts-using-smsmanager-in-the-default-android-text-application) (Your mileage may vary).

```
// code shamelessly copied from link above
Context context; //you should initialize it somewhere
...
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", number);
values.put("body", message );
values.put("date", time );
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be adding the entry into the content provider: Something like this on succesfuly sending the SMS:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", mPhoneNumber);
            values.put("body",message);
            getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```